# Find backward in string first substring that belongs to a set (regex?)

Tags: regex, swift, substring

I have a set of string `set` and I would like to find the first occurrence of one string of `set` as a substring of a string `string`.
I would like to search in the backward direction from `position` (an integer).

I have written a code that uses a for loop but I would like to be able to write it in a more compact way, maybe regex are needed.

Can you please help me?

EDIT. my temporary solution: `currentPosition` is an integer value given by a `NSTextView`, `command` is the string I am manipulating, what I am doing now is checking if the character after the one at `currentPosition` is `" "` or if it is the last of the string `command`. In such cases I extrapolate the substring of `command` that spaces from `currentPosition` to the nearest (in the backward direction) delimiter (defined in my code).

What in my question is called `set` here is an array of String and it is represented by `separators`, what was `string` here is `command`, and what was `position` here is `currentPosition`.

```
let currentPosition = self.selectedRange().location
let currentPositionIndex = command.index(command.startIndex,offsetBy: currentPosition)
if(currentPosition == command.characters.count || command[currentPositionIndex] == " ")  {
    let separatorsString = " .,:~/!+=\\;/?"
    let separators = separatorsString.characters
    //TODO: use regex in order to clean the code
    var nearestSeparatorPosition = command.startIndex
    outerloop: for i in stride(from: currentPosition - 1, to: -1, by: -1) {
        for separator in separators {
            let index = command.index(command.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
            if(command[index] == separator) {
                nearestSeparatorPosition = command.index(index, offsetBy: 1)
                break outerloop
            }
        }
    }
    Swift.print("current word index = (\(command.distance(from: command.startIndex, to: nearestSeparatorPosition)),\(command.distance(from: command.startIndex, to: currentPositionIndex)))")
    let currentWord = command.substring(with: nearestSeparatorPosition ..< currentPositionIndex)
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do. Could you post your code that uses a `for` loop please?

Comment: @ganzogo Yes, I will post it tomorrow early morning (in Italy it is late), since I want to made some modifications first.

Comment: @ganzogo it is difficult to going to bed when programming, I am editing my question and posting my temporary solution

Comment: I still don't really get what you are trying to do. Could you post working code (or nearly working) with actual input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have some things flipped around, but based un my understanding of your question this is what I would do:

```
func findFirstContaining(needle item: String, in haystack: [String]) -> String? {

    let stringRanges: [Range<String.Index>] = haystack.flatMap { return item.range(of: $0) } .sorted { $0.lowerBound < $1.lowerBound }
    if let range = stringRanges.first {
        return item.substring(with: range)
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}

let testSet: Set<String> = ["test", "string", "set"]

let needle = "this is a test"

// evaluates to "test"
let result = findFirstContaining(needle: needle, in: testSet.sorted())

let reversedResult = findFirstContaining(needle: needle, in: testSet.sorted().reversed())
```

This is probably inefficient, but I'm not exactly sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow I will read it, for the moment I post my solution.